# change of source foreach to other

Tags: javascript, foreach

```
Manager example 

// Create a new array
var gryfindor = [];

// Loop through each wizard
wizards.forEach(function (wizard) {
    // If the wizard is in Gryfindor, push to the new array
    if (wizard.house === 'Gryfindor') {
        gryfindor.push(wizard);
    }
});
```

My manager asked me to write this thing into in this format below:

```
// Create a new array from the wizard array
var gryfindor = wizards.filter(function (wizard) {
    // Only include wizards from the Gryfindor house
    return wizard.house === 'Gryfindor';
});
```

I need to change the foeeach in JavaScript but I don't know how to do anyone can write it or encode

```
var isExist = false;    
var cashoutIndex = 0;    
CashOutData.forEach((item, index) => {    
    if (item.id === userBets[0][i].id) {    
        isExist = true;    
        cashoutIndex = index;        
    }    
});
```

Change of for each loop and faster the performance

answer as per manager required format

Comment: Your `.forEach` seems to be acting as a `.findLastIndex` rather than a `.filter`

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. This is not a coding service.

Comment: @JaromandaX can you explain more or can you write down the update code

Comment: no, you want to use `.filter` but your code isn't filtering - so, how can I write code if not even you know what you want?

Comment: @JaromandaX while in code after the equal comparison it had to add with html if equals add with one else add with other so i used for each loop but now performance slow so can you write the logic

Comment: your code doesn't show that

Comment: how write the code with the filter for the above condition

Comment: my code is working but if a huge amount of data will come means it will not work can you write down the correct logic

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not need to enumerate every item in the list in most cases.

The following code finds the index of the first matching element, and then constructs the response accordingly.

`Boolean(~index)` uses the bitwise NOT operator to convert the not found signal (`-1`) from `findIndex` to a falsy number (`0`).

```js
const go = (data, userBets) =>  {
  const index = data.findIndex(({id}, i) => 
      id === userBets[0]?.[i]?.id)
  return [ Boolean(~index), index === -1 ? 0 : index ]
}

const [ isExist, cashoutIndex ] = go(CashOutData, userBets)
```